# Reference for curves over non algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Does anyone have a good reference for curves over non algebraically closed non perfect fields that doesn't use the language of schemes ?

I'm looking for a book or notes that would cover the material on algebraic curves given in Diamond,Schurman A first course in modular form. Mainly I am looking for the equivalence of categories between algebraic curves and function fields. Althoug note that i'm also looking for the situation over non perfect field which isn't mentionned in Diamond Shurman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found these notes by Prof. Hida : http://www.math.ucla.edu/~hida/207b.1.12w/Lec12w.pdf
Which, although it didn't contain everything I wanted I really liked and in fact was very well suited for my needs.